# Javascript can't access document: null or undefined

Tags: javascript, scope, global

`document.getElementsByName('name').value` returns `undefined`.  I don't have the foggiest idea as to why this is the case.

I included the .js file correctly, Firebug doesn't find any errors in my code, and the code fails within the first line or two because each time I call the above mentioned function, it returns `undefined`.  This has me completely confused.

Here is how I included the file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>
```

Here is all the code needed to reach the first undefined value returned by a function call:

```
    function myfunction() {
        var myvar = document.getElementsByName('myElement').value;
```

...and I get undefined variables at that point.  The button I use to trigger the script uses the following code:

```
    <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">MyButton</button>
```

1. Does the type of button I have effect what information is available to the script?
2. How do I find out why `document.getElementsByName()` returns `undefined`?
3. Does the Javascript `document` object have any scope issues with scripts that are imported from another file?

Sorry if this is a dumb question.  I'm very new to Javascript.

EDIT: Thank you Mike Samuel for your answer.  That fixed it like a charm and I wonder why I didn't know this before?  I should have at leased guesses as much seeing as how getElementsByName() suggests there's more than one value returned...

Comment: `document.getElementByName` is not cross browser so yes it could potentially return bizarre values or nothing at all.  It would probably easier to assign an ID or get the element by tag name.

Comment: @Lime - there is no "getElementByName", the method you seek is *getElementsByName*, which every browser supporting DOM 1 has (which is pretty much every browser since Navigator 2).

Comment: @RobG Spelling error =) Anyways, IE 9 still hasn't gotten `getElementsByName` [correct](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125).  I definitely wouldn't call the quirky behavior cross browser.  Without having more context of what `document.getElementsByName("myElement")` is, he could be running into a browser bug.

Comment: All three of the functions listed below are in the W3C dom1 standard.

Comment: @Lime - if you stick the the HTML standard (that is, HTML 4.01) and only use names on elements that are specified to have names (there are 14 of them), and do not have names on some elements that are the same as the id of other elements, then it is reliable. If you expect browsers to support features of HTML5, which is not a standard (it is a working draft) and is not fully implemented by any browser, then you will have issues.

Comment: @SinthiaV Yeah and 2 out of the 3 functions listed don't follow the W3C DOM1 standard in IE.

Comment: @RobG The polluted namespace issue of ID's and names isn't following the DOM1 standard.  I gave up on HTML5 years ago ;)

Comment: @Lime - yes, IE is a pain in how it thinks name and id are the same thing, but if you stick to the rules I outlined *getElementsByName* works fine. Agree that HTML5 is not viable on the general web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns an array-like object containing elements, not an element.  Stick a `[0]` before `.value`.

```
var myvar = document.getElementsByName('myElement')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has 3 different functions which apply in situations like this.

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________________
|getElementById()       | Accesses the first element with the specified id.          |
|                       | Returns a single element, as ID's are unique in a document |
|_______________________|____________________________________________________________|
|getElementsByName()    | Accesses all elements with a specified name.               |
|                       | Returns an array of all elements marked with this name.    |
|                       | Used like a CSS class(not unique).                         |
|_______________________|____________________________________________________________|
|getElementsByTagName() | Accesses all elements with a specified tagname.            |
|                       | Returns an array of all elements with a given tag.         |
|_______________________|____________________________________________________________|
```

Use ID when you want a specific single element, name for an arbitrary group (access as an array with an index) and tag when you want all of the same type of element (also by indexed array). 
Good luck and happy coding ;-}